# Three js custom material affected by light

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have this material:

```
<script id="vertexShader2" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() 
{ 
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<!-- fragment shader a.k.a. pixel shader -->
<script id="fragmentShader2" type="x-shader/x-vertex"> 
uniform sampler2D baseTexture;
uniform float baseSpeed;
uniform sampler2D noiseTexture;
uniform float noiseScale;
uniform float alpha;
uniform float time;

varying vec2 vUv;
void main() 
{
    vec2 uvTimeShift = vUv + vec2( -0.7, 1.5 ) * time * baseSpeed;  
    vec4 noiseGeneratorTimeShift = texture2D( noiseTexture, uvTimeShift );
    vec2 uvNoiseTimeShift = vUv + noiseScale * vec2( noiseGeneratorTimeShift.r, noiseGeneratorTimeShift.b );
    vec4 baseColor = texture2D( baseTexture, uvNoiseTimeShift );

    baseColor.a = alpha;
    gl_FragColor = baseColor;
}  
</script>


    var noiseTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/wormholes/cloud.png' );
                        noiseTexture.wrapS = noiseTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 

                        var lavaTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "img/planets/"+value['texture_clouds'] );
                        lavaTexture.wrapS = lavaTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 

                        this.earthUniforms = {
                            baseTexture:    { type: "t", value: lavaTexture },
                            baseSpeed:      { type: "f", value: 0.001 },
                            noiseTexture:   { type: "t", value: noiseTexture },
                            noiseScale:     { type: "f", value: 0.07337 },
                            alpha:          { type: "f", value: 10.0 },
                            time:           { type: "f", value: 1.0 }
                        };
                        animatedSurfaces.push(earthUniforms);

                        var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( 
                        {
                            uniforms: earthUniforms,
                              vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexShader2'   ).textContent,
                              fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader2' ).textContent,
                            specular   : new THREE.Color("rgb(255,255,255)"),
                            shininess  : 0.1,                              
                            depthTest  : 0,
                            blending   : 1,
                            transparent: true,
                            bumpScale  : 1, //0.8
                            bumpMap    : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "img/planets/"+value['texture_clouds_alpha'] ),
                            map        : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "img/planets/"+value['texture_clouds'] ),
                            color      : 0xffffff,
                            //opacity    : 0.1,
                            emissive   : new THREE.Color("rgb(30,22,20)"),
                            alphaMap   : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "img/planets/"+value['texture_clouds_alpha']),
                        });
```

It is reacting with light like MeshBasic material.
I need to react like MeshLambert material with alpha map.

It means to configure material black color in "lavatexture" to be  transparent, and reacting on light source. Lighted side to have diffuse color, and side in shadow to have specular color.

How to solve this, when uniforms don't let material to behive like meshLambertMaterial, i cant set diffuse and specular color.

But i need that uniforms effect. (lava effect http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Animate.html)

r71

Comment: Questions a bit confusing. You just want your material affected by lights?. I have a [blog post here](http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial) in which I add my experiments with custom shaders. Maybe the last one will interest you as I added lights.

Comment: Thank you for direction. Will try to play with.